# 1999 ford f350 will not start under 50 degrees

Tags: ford, diesel, f-350

If my 99 ford f350 with a 7.3 diesel is not plugged in it will not start under 50 degrees what should I check?

Comment: When you say, "Won't start" you mean it won't crank or it won't fire when you are turning it over? More than likely your glow plugs are not working optimally, but based on your question, I'm not sure.

Comment: won't fire cranks good glow plugs or glow plug relay

Comment: it was glow plugs

Comment: can't be sure but here's an old trick I learnt in the Victorian high country (Australia)
during icy conditions when diesel won't start.Pour hot water over manifold.Will not solve
your problem but good to know.
mike western australia

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I'd suggest you take a look at the glow plugs and/or the glow plug relay. Here is a YouTube video which should explain how to check the relay:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9wxR1yToAs

[Here is the link](https://www.google.com/search?q=98+ford+f350+check+glow+plugs) to the Google search I used to find it, which may even provide better results.